# pandas add rows based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming I have this dataframe:

```
    X     Y
0   a     1
1   b    10
2   c    11
3   d   100
4   e   101
5   f   110
6   g   111
```

I would like to decompose the column Y into rows so that each number with more than one digit 1 is broken into another number with only one digit 1. For example, the number 111, is broken to 3 rows with values 100, 10, and 1, and keeps the information from other columns. Here is a visualization of what I expect:

```
    X     Y
0   a     1
1   b    10
2   c    10
3   c     1
4   d   100
5   e   100
6   e     1
7   f   100
8   f    10
9   g   100
10  g    10
11  g     1
```

Here is what I have done so far, but I wonder if there is a more pythonic way to do it. Appreciate your help in advance.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'X':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o'], 'Y':[1,10,11,100,101,110,111,1000,1001,1010,1011,1100,1101,1110,1111] })
print(df)

for i in range(len(df)):
    value  = int(df.at[i,'Y'])
    digits = len(str(value))
    opts   = sum(map(int, str(value)))
    
    if opts > 1:
        # assign first value
        temp = df.loc[[i]]
        temp.at[i,'Y'] = 10**(digits-1)
        
        # update row
        df   = df.drop([i])
        df   = df.append(temp)

        # append new rows
        while value != 1:
            value  = int(str(value)[1:])
            if value == 0: break
            digits = len(str(value))
            temp.at[i,'Y'] = 10**(digits-1)
            df     = df.append(temp)
            
df = df.sort_index()
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: What about 117? Should it become 100, 10, 7? Or 100, 10, 1 seven times? Or 17 as 10 and 1 seven times?

Comment: The number can only be made of zeros and ones

Comment: Once you have a decompose function that can take a number and return its 10 powers as a list you can simply explode to get what you need. Check out the solution I proposed below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try applying a decompose function like this and then simply `explode`.

The decompose function takes 111 and returns `[100,10,1]` or takes 110 and returns `[100,10]`. It does it by enumerating over each of the digits as a string in reverse and multiplying it to 10^i. Then returning it as a list without any 0s.

```
decompose = lambda x: [10**i for i,j in enumerate(str(x)[::-1]) if int(j)!=0]

df['Y'] = df['Y'].apply(decompose)
out = df.explode('Y')
print(out)
```

```
   X    Y
0  a    1
1  b   10
2  c    1
2  c   10
3  d  100
4  e    1
4  e  100
5  f   10
5  f  100
6  g    1
6  g   10
6  g  100
```

**EDIT:** This is only for the specific condition mentioned by OP where `The number can only be made of zeros and ones`. In general cases, please use the lambda function - **Courtsey [@Joe Ferndz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13873980/joe-ferndz)**

```
lambda x: [10**i for i,a in enumerate(str(x)[::-1]) for _ in range(int(a))]
```

Comment: Upvoted your answer. and deleted my answer. Btw. your answer will not solve for 1234. It will just give 1000, 100,10,1 and not give it 1000, 100, 100, 10,10,10,1,1,1,1 as my solution gives. You need to iterate through the list once more

Comment: Here's what you need to do `df['Y'] = df['Y'].apply(lambda x: [10**i for i,a in enumerate(str(x)[::-1]) for _ in range(int(a))])`

Comment: Yes, I had proposed a more general function earlier for that, but OP mentioned its going to be only 1s and 0s. `The number can only be made of zeros and ones`